# Splitting short options from long options

Tags: bash

I have a string of short and options, which I want to split into short and long options strings.

```
opts="-p,--plong,--pext"
```

My idea has been to use grep, which does have a problem for short options.

```
opts="-p,--plong,--pext"
short_opts=$(echo "$opts" | grep -o '\s*-\w*')
long_opts=$(echo "$opts" | grep -o '\s*--\w*')
echo
echo "short_opts: $short_opts"
echo "long_opts: $long_opts"
```

Comment: `\w` is not standard in `grep` ,looks like you use GNU `grep`

Comment: `\s*-\w*` matches just `-`, which just might be your problem.

Comment: then again, what's the point of the whole exercise here? Just create two variables from the go: `shortopts=-p longopts='--plong,--pext'` and be done with it.

Comment: I want it to be user-supplied.  The less variables users have to supply the better.

Answer (score 2):

In zsh instead of bash, you could do:

```
opts="-p,--plong,--pext"

# split on ,s into an array
opts=( ${(s[,])opts} )

short_opts=( ${opts:#--*} )
long_opts=( ${(M)opts:#--*} )
```

Then, you get two arrays:

```
$ typeset -p short_opts long_opts
typeset -a short_opts=( -p )
typeset -a long_opts=( --plong --pext )
```

To do a stricter matching, such as allow only short options with `-` followed by one any only one character other than `-`, and long options with `--` followed by one or more characters other than `=`:

```
set -o extendedglob
short_opts=( ${(M)opts:#-[^-]} )
long_opts=( ${(M)opts:#--[^=]##} )
```

---

bash doesn't have a splitting operator (like the `s` parameter expansion flag of zsh above), but it does the infamous split+glob upon unquoted expansions inherited from the Bourne shell. So you could use that to do the splitting¹:

```
IFS=, # split on ,
set -o noglob
opts=( $opts )
```

It doesn't have array filtering operators like zsh's `${array:#pattern}` operator, but it has ksh93's `${array[@]/pattern/replacement}` array member editing operator, and leaving that expansion unquoted removes empty elements, so you could do (assuming `noglob` is still on and `$IFS` is empty or still contains only `,`):

```
short_options=( ${opts[@]/#--*} )
long_options=( ${opts[@]/#-[!-]*} )
```

`#` anchors the pattern at the start. `%` would anchor at the end, but bash contrary to zsh doesn't support anchoring both at the start and end, so you can't match elements as a whole. You can always loop over all the elements and use `case` for matching if you needed to do a stricter matching:

```
short_opts=() long_opts=()
shopt -s extglob
for opt in "${opts[@]}"; do
  case $opt in
    ( -[^-]     ) short_opts+=( "$opt" );;
    ( --+([^=]) ) long_opts+=( "$opt" );;
  esac
done
```

---

<sup>¹ Like ksh, bash changed the `$IFS` meaning from being `S`eparators to being delimiters/terminators though, which means `a,,b,` would be split into `a`, the empty string and `b` without an extra empty string. Not a problem here if all elements are options</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this

```
opts="-p,--plong,--pext"
for opt in ${opts//,/ }; do
  if [[ "$opt" == --* ]]; then
    long_opts="$long_opts $opt"
  elif [[ "$opt" == -* ]]; then
    short_opts="$short_opts $opt"
  fi
done

echo
echo "short_opts: $short_opts"
echo "long_opts: $long_opts"
```

Comment: you're using bash, so you really should use arrays, not space-delimited scalar variables.  arrays are a great way of avoiding many of the word-splitting issues common to shell scripting.

Comment: `${opts//,/ }` changes the `,` to space and then performs split+glob, hoping that `$IFS` contains space and no other character found in the elements, and doing glob which doesn't make sense. You'd want to set `$IFS` to `,` and disable glob instead (and then you can do `for opt in $opts`)